# Don't understand how JavaScript assign operator interacts with a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, assign

My problem is that I don't understand how assign operator is interpreted and interacts with a function. Let me explain

I was changing the state of my component, and I was doing something wrong that I couldn't see until I realize it, of course.

My component:

```
class UpdateLifeCycle extends Component {
  state = { src: urls[this.props.election] };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {    
    this.setState = { src: urls[nextProps.election] };    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Selected {this.props.election}</p>        
        <img //
          alt={this.props.election}
          src={this.state.src}
          witdh="250"
        />
        <p>{urls[this.props.election]}</p>
        <p>{this.state.src}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I was doing, and is wrong is this piece

```
this.setState = { src: urls[nextProps.election] };
```

and what I should be doing is passing it as a parameter instead of assigning it.

```
this.setState({ src: urls[nextProps.election] });
```

Why does the JS interpreter allow you to assign and object to a function, and where is that object being assigned?

Comment: Because the function is just a prop like any other, the object is being assigned to the setState prop of the component instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`setState` is a **variable** which currently holds a `function`.  There is nothing stopping you from changing its value and add an object there, because it *is* a variable.  JavaScript was influenced by other functional programming languages and it is okay to assign a function to a variable.

**Explanation**

`state` is a special object in a React component, which you would access as `this.state`.  `setState` is a special function in a React component, which allows you to modify the state.  Actions are dispatched when the state is updated, however you should not directly modify the state of a React component, and should always use `setState`.

`setState` is another variable in a JavaScript `class` (Your React Component is a class-based component), which by default holds the function to modify the `state` variable.
You can override a variable in JavaScript and when you assign an object (the new state you wanted) to `setState`, you are changing the value of `setState` which can no longer now update the `state` variable.

You would find React's [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) helpful.